# Git in VS Code says I've got unmerged files, but I'm sure I have merged them

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I am trying to merge a Git repo I have on Azure DevOps Services (ADS), using Visual Studio Code. I have no experience using VS Code and merging into a Git repo. I've got conflicts, but I thought that I had resolved them by accepting all incoming changes (which is what I wanted to do).

If I understand it correctly, I only had one conflict, which I've resolved. So, now in the side bar (I don't know the proper name for it in VS Code) there's lots of files with either with an "A" next to them or a "M" next to them. "A" I would think means a file that's to be added. "M" is a modification, that has, if I understand it correctly, already been accounted for by Git in VS Code.

I've issued a `Merge branch` command, followed by the feature branch that I'm trying to merge into the master branch. What I don't understand is why VS Code keeps complaining to me that I've got problems,

> Git: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files

What unmerged files? How do I identify them? There are two buttons, one that says Cancel (which is obvious what that does) and the other that says, "Open Git Log". I pressed that button I don't know how many times, but if it's supposed to open a log file for me, I sure would like to know where I'm supposed to find the window with the log file in it, because it isn't obvious to me that it's anywhere at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Ctrl+Shift+U to open the output tab and get the detail error message:

```
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
U       ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/Program.cs
```

We need use the cmd `git add {file name}` to add the file again, then we can commit it.

In addition, we also can see the error message in the output tab

[image]

Comment: Hi Vito, I have 1 merge change, which I thought I'd already taken care of, because I accepted all changed from the feature branch to the master branch. Plus 52 staged changes. If I hover my mouse of the ```Merge Changes```, it does give me an option to stage the change. Should I do that?

Comment: BTW, Vito, I do get those 4 lines in the OUTPUT tab in VS Code, starting with error:, hint:, hint: and fatal:. However, there's no file listed after that.

Comment: I went ahead and staged the file that was reported as being capable of being staged. Then I tried again to merge the branches. That time, it finally let me merge the branches. I thought pushed it to origin/master. WOW, that was not easy. And it didn't help that VS Code would NOT tell me what file was causing the problem.